# Getting nil error when adding elements in Array - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to get a number from the user, store this number in the array and then add everything in the array together to display a total.

```
names = Array.new(20)
sum = 0

x = 0

for index in 0..5
  puts "Enter a number: "
  data = gets.to_i
  names.push data
  x = x + names[index]
end

puts x
```

But I am getting the error `` rb:10:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError) ``

I guess its not allowing me to add whatever is in the array together. Anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: `x = x + data` – there's no need to fetch the element from the array again.

Comment: Yes I know that, i am just trying to learn about array, So I was trying to get the value from the array instead

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code.

`Array.new(20)` – you probably think this creates an array of the given size. Well, it does, but it also fills the array with a default object of `nil`:

```
Array.new(3)
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

In Ruby, you just create an empty array. It will grow and shrink automatically. And instead of `Array.new` you can use an [array literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Arrays):

```
names = []
```

---

`for index in 0..5` – `for` loops are very unidiomatic. You should use one of these:

```
(0..5).each do |index|
  # ...
end

0.upto(5) do |index|
  # ...
end

6.times do |index|
  # ...
end
```

---

And finally:

```
names.push data
x = x + names[index]
```

You are pushing an element to the end of the array and then fetch it from the array using an absolute index. This only works if `index` and array size correlate exactly.

It's more robust to either use an explicit index for both, storing and fetching:

```
names[index] = data
x = x + names[index]
```

or to fetch the [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#last-method) element: (note that `index` isn't needed)

```
names.push data
x = x + names.last
```

Ruby also provides negative indices that are relative to the array's end:

```
names.push data
x = x + names[-1]
```

Needless to say, you could just omit the fetching:

```
names.push data
x = x + data
```

---

It might be useful to separate the data gathering from the calculation:

```
numbers = []

6.times do
  puts 'Enter a number: '
  numbers << gets.to_i
end
```

and then:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # <- example input

numbers.sum
#=> 21

# -- or --

numbers.inject(:+)
#=> 21

# -- or --

sum = 0
numbers.each { |n| sum += n }
sum
#=> 21
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, Ruby clearly works very differently to Java. I am familiar with Java so was using my knowledge from there to code in Ruby but there is clearly a much bigger learning curve

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the array with 20 nil names. Then you push the first entered number to the array (position 21) and try to concat the position [0] (names[0]) that is nil.

Try to change the first line:

```
names = Array.new
```

Comment: The argument is superfluous, you can just write `names = Array.new` or simply `names = []`

Comment: Edited as sugested by Stefan